# Error while passing StorageAccount Key to new Context

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

Following code was working fine until yesterday but today it is giving me an error as mentioned below.

```
$StorageAccountName = "xyz"
$StorageAccountKey = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey.Primary
```

Tried replacing the last line in above code with

```
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey.key1
```

Here's the error:

```
New-AzureStorageContext : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'StorageAccountKey'. The argument is null or empty.
Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey
 $StorageAccountKey.value[0]
```

You could easily figure that out yourself with `$StorageAccount | Get-Member`

Comment: This has worked but out of curiosity wanted to know the problem with using `$StorageAccountKey.Primary` or `$StorageAccountKey.key1`

Comment: well, I've explained it to you. the `$StorageAccountKey` object doesn't have those properties anymore, you can check yourself, do the ` | gm` and see.